# How to make multi character delimiter in Coldfusion for cfloop?

Tags: string, coldfusion

I have a String variable which has dynamic user entered text

EX:- `<cfset setPars="SPTO_DATE('04/11/2009 11:59:59 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')SP(L','MN)>'`

Now If I use `SP` as the delimiter

in CFloop as below

```
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" To="#ListLen(setPars,'SP')#">
       <br/> #ListGetAT(setPars,i,'SP')# 
    </cfloop>
```

I am getting output As

```
TO_DATE('04/11/2009 11:59:59 

M', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:
```

But I want as

```
TO_DATE('04/11/2009 11:59:59 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')

(L','MN)
```

Is there any way in Coldfusion to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not a direct way to do this.  However, there are a couple of different ways to accomplish it.

What I usually do is replace the multichararacter delimiter with a single character.  I usually use the bell (chr(7)) because it's not typable on a standard keyboard.

```
<cfset list = replace(setPars, 'SP', '#chr(7)#', 'all')>
```

Then, you can loop over the list:

```
<cfloop list="#list#" index="i" delimiters="#chr(7)#">
    <br />#i#
</cfloop>
```

Note the simpler loop operator.  It will save you some work.

Comment: I use CHR(30) (RECORD SEPARATOR) the same way. Seems less dangerous and the character was designed for just that. Personal preference, I guess.

Comment: There's also `ListChangeDelims`. Using your example: `<cfset list=ListChangeDelims(setPars, CHR(7) , "SP") />`

Comment: ListChangeDelims treats "SP" as a list of delimiters "S" and "P" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function instead.

For example, you can split a string by a string delimiter like this:

```
 "string&^&string&^&string".split("&^&")
```

Comment: Just be aware `split(regex)` accepts a regular expression. So you need to escape special characters, like the caret `^` in the above expression ie `theString.split("&\^&")`. Also, CF10 supports [multi-character delimiters](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListToArray) (finally!).

Answer (score 0):

Not using the built-in `List*()` functions, no. They all treat the delimiter argument as a set of characters, rather than a literal string. But you can, of course, use the regular string functions (e.g. `Find()`, `Mid()`, etc.) to do the parsing yourself.

Also, for what it's worth, your loop can be written more compactly (as long as you don't care about the numeric indices of each list item) as:

```
<cfloop index="i" list="#setPars#">
   <br/> #i#
</cfloop>
```